# Unbounded Hilbert Transform of $C_{c}(\mathbb{R})$ Function

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, asymptotics, harmonic-analysis

I want to give an example of a continuous, compactly supported function (denoted $C_{c}(\mathbb{R})$) $f$, such that the distribution $H(f)$, where $H$ is the Hilbert transform, does not coincide with a continuous function. I.e., there does not a continuous function $g$ such that

$$\langle{Hf,\phi}\rangle=\langle{g,\phi}\rangle,\quad\forall \phi\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$$

My attempt was the function

$$f(y):=\dfrac{\text{sgn}(y)}{\log\left|y\right|}\phi(y)$$

where $\phi$ is a smooth cutoff function which avoids the singularity at $y=\pm 1$.

It's easy to show that the principal value integral giving $H$ diverges to $\infty$ in modulus at the origin, as there is no cancellation. However, I could not rigorously (at least by an argument I found convincing) show that

$$\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0}\int_{\left|y\right|\geq\delta}\dfrac{\text{sgn}(x-y)\phi(x-y)}{y\log\left|x-y\right|}dy$$

blows up as $x\rightarrow 0$. Does anyone have any suggestions for showing this? Alternatively, is there a simpler way to find such an example? I was thinking perhaps stacked copies of trapezoid functions converging in distribution to the characteristic function $\chi_{[-1,1]}$ might work. But I didn't calculate the Hilbert transform of a trapezoid function.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track, but let's make it easier. Let $f(y) = |1/\ln y\,|(1-y)^2, 0 < y <1$ and $f=0$ elsewhere. For $x<0, f(x+y)$ has support in $(0,\infty).$ Thus for such $x, f(x+y)/y \ge 0.$ As $x\to 0^-, f(x+y)/y \to f(y)/y = $ pointwise a.e. So by Fatou's Lemma,

$$\infty = \int f(y)/y\,dy \le \liminf_{x\to 0^-}\int f(x+y)/y\,dy.$$

This gives the desired blow up. Now that's not quite the Hilbert transform there at the end, but a simple modification will give what you need.

Comment: Just to clarify, $f(y):=\dfrac{(1-y)^{2}}{\left|\ln\left|y\right|\right|}$ on $0<y<1$ and $f=0$ elsewhere? Fatou's lemma is technically a sequential statement. But if I have a continuous function $g$ which equals $H(f)$ a.e., then there exists a sequence of points $x_{k}\rightarrow 0^{-}$ such that $H(f)(x_{k})=g(x_{k})$ for all $k$, then $\left\|g\right\|_{\infty}=\infty$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Yes on the first question. FL, MCT,DCT all work in the real parameter setting. (If not, then there is a subsequence ...)

Comment: After taking a second look, it seems like you're ignoring the fact that the integrals defining the Hilbert transform are defined only in a principal value sense; they are not absolutely convergent.

Comment: I think you can modify your argument though as follows. Let $x_{k}\rightarrow 0^{-}$. For each $k$, let $\delta_{k}>0$ be sufficiently small so that $\int_{\left|y\right|\geq\delta_{k}}\frac{f(x_{k}+y)}{y}dy$ is $2^{-k}$-close to $H(f)(x_{k})$.  Then apply Fatou's lemma to $\int_{\left|y\right|\geq\delta_{k}}\frac{f(x_{k}+y)}{y}dy$.

Comment: The PV integral equals the regular integral if $f(x+y)/y\in L^1(\mathbb R),$ which is true for $x<0.$ (That's why I chose $f$ the way I did and looked at $x<0.$)

Comment: You are right--my apologies.